# Should I obfuscate/disguise (file) names in certificate exams?

Tags: oscp

I have 0 experience taking exams for security certificates. When I'm taking an exam for something like OSCP, should I obfuscate/disguise my files and names (like naming a file `update.sh`) to make it harder for "future testers and auditors" to find like a criminal would, or just make them obvious (naming a file `exploit.sh`) for the examiner(s) to understand my reports more easily, or does the naming of my files and folders (and variables and functions) not matter at all?

Comment: I use my own naming scheme that only I understand and document it if required/needed.

Comment: To prevent accidental click in the electronic report, you can **mask** the file name/URL but NOT obfuscate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OSCP certification is not about criminal activity. You're excepted to write a detailed report explaining exactly what you did. Hence there is no need to hide anything. If you are sneaky and cause backdoors to be left behind on pentests or red team engagements you are actively lowering the security posture of the systems you are testing which is bad.

Comment: The OSCP is only an example I used. Are most or all certificate exams like that? (I'm not gonna name everyone of them)

Comment: My point still stands, unless the exam calls for you to avoid detection you shouldn't do so. Also the filename doesn't do much if the content of the file has a known bad hash so you would need a more elaborate scheme if you did need to hide.